# Notification from sql new object when user login - Django

Tags: python, html, sql, django, visual-studio

My query is the next:
How can I display a notification to a user who logged for the first time after the action that created the notification has been executed.
In my case I want the user to get notified when he win something.

Comment: Do you have an existing notification model and example of creating and/or displaying it?

Comment: I have the model, but I cant figure out how to delete the notification when the user reads it.